# Show template in Joomla (parameter)

Tags: url, templates, joomla

I know it is possible in Joomla! to set the template temporarily to another template with an URL parameter. What is the parameter? And how should the template be indicated?
I expect something like

```
index.php?template=mytemplate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the template manager and click on one and then edit, there is a preview button where you can see it in a form in the browser.  There is also a link there that says "Open in new window."  When I click that it loads my site with this as the query "?tp=1&template=ja_purity"

Comment: that's exactly the way I found out! :-) 
Furthermore 'tp=1' shows all the placeholders for the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh... sorry, found it myself.

Lets share it:

```
index.php?template=directoryname
```

I was using the template name as declared in the XML file, instead of using the directory in the template folder (/templates/directoryname)